# Is there an anisotropy factor (g factor) for TDDFT Abs and CD calculations?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, chirality, density-functional-theory

Experimentally, anisotropy factor is calculated by dividing the CD spectra by the absorbance spectra multiplying by a factor of 32980 (in order to get a nondimensional quantity)

Theoretical calculations can be performed via TDDFT to obtain rotatory and oscillatory strengths, obtaining excitations for each case and adjusting, for each excitation, a curve, obtaining then the "theoretical absorbance/CD spectra".

How can then we define a theoretical anisotropy factor, does it have sense?
Should another calculation be performed?

Would you divide both adjusted curves or divide the corresponding excitations, adjusting a new set of curves to what you get?

Any clues?

Comment: This question would probably fit better on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 6 months is long for no answer. Why not copy and paste into the Materials.SE that @Tyberius recommended?

Comment: Well lets try (back then I think it wasn't still active, there was a petition for it to open), thanks!